# How to submit new state-by-state information to the Data Repository

Tags: data, curated-data, wolfram-cloud, entity, wolfram-data-framework

I'm interested in [algorithms for apportioning seats of Congress to states after every decennial Census](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/apportioning-representatives-in-the-united-states-congress-hills-method-of-apportionment), for which I'm using Mathematica to test different functions. To this end, I wrote a Notebook that pulls down the [decennial population counts](https://www.census.gov/data/tables/2010/dec/popchange-data-text.html) (which sometimes different marginally from the built-in population counts in USState entities because of the source, which may be culled from the American Community Survey) as well as [historical apportionments](https://www.census.gov/data/tables/2010/dec/apportionment-data-text.html)--both from Census.gov--and [two-letter state abbreviations](http://about.usps.com/who-we-are/postal-history/state-abbreviations.htm) from the Post Office.

I've publicly published both the [Notebook for gathering the data](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/christopher.e.wilson/Published/getPopulationApportionment.nb) and [the data itself](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/1a4bfb31-d5d4-49e3-9e04-4cf80e1fae1b) on the Wolfram Cloud.

Now I would like to submit this data to the Wolfram Data Repository. I've read the general guidelines for submitting new data to the Repo, but it's not clear to me whether this should be submitted as a standalone extra data resource or, ideally, data that would be baked into the `USState` entities, ideally as properties like `DecennialPopulation` and `Representatives` that would default to the most recent but allow for a specified decade, same as with current population data.

Advice on how to proceed, ideally with examples of how to submit this sort of data? I've read the overview of how the data resources work, but am still working through the mechanics of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can submit your data for publication in the data repository by turning it into a ResourceObject and using ResourceSubmit.

There is a notebook interface for turning data into a ResourceObject with all the appropriate metadata. You can open it with CreateNotebook["DataResource"]

You will also need a published id to submit to the data repository. You can request one here:
https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/request-publisher-id

Comment: Thanks -- I see how to submit data, but not how to potentially integrate it into existing entities.

Comment: The best way to do that is to define an EntityStore, which takes some work but once it is done you can use $EntityStores to integrate it into the entity framework.

Comment: The resources here are the best examples: https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/type/Entity-Store/